# Combine multiple jar files in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, jar, android-studio, aar

Our company has an application that is built upon some proprietary 3rd party libs (jar files). I need to make an API for our app but need the 3rd party lib jars to not be directly accessible or at least hidden from the user.

I was thinking the simplest solution would be to compile the 3rd party jars into my library jar file but I can't figure out how to do this.

Any ideas or advice on how to do this?

Comment: You could try to unzip all your jar in a single directory and zip that back. Hopefully there won't be any conflict. But then how would you version your JAR? How will you easily update a specific library ? And nothing will prevent the user to unzip this JAR anyway. I'm feeling you're going the wrong way about that.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. If the 3rd party libs are updated, then I need to repackage my files each time but I can't think of a better solution.

Comment: Just use every JAR, they'll be packaged in the APK I don't see your problem. Won't change anything having all of them or just one. If you want to make it less obvious what you use, just rename the jars with some private naming.

Comment: It's for an AAR file which will be reused & could be unpacked. The lead developer here doesn't want the JAR libs to be seen or used but I've left it as is for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamic load framework in android. Some like this:https://github.com/reasonpun/MofunDynamicLoadApk